# Custom taxonomy template for categories

Tags: categories, templates, taxonomy

I have just been reading up alot about custom taxonomy template files, I have a category within a custom taxonomy that needs its own template.

I understand about the template heirarchy etc.. and seen other posts relating to this.

I think that my file should be named taxonomy-{taxonomy-slug}-{category-slug}.php, is that right?

Though I have already tried taxonomy-ait-dir-item-category-events.php where ait-dir-item-category is the name of the taxonomy and events is the name of the category, changed the page title to make it stand out and it didn't affect anything.

Could someone please advise? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your terminology is a bit scrambled here. A custom taxonomy is a [**taxonomy**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) which you manually register through [`register_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy). In your case that is *ait-dir-item-category*.

Any "category" (as you call it) you create in your custom taxonomy is called a *term*. In this case events.

To create a custom page for events, you need to name your template *taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php*. Take a look at the [**Template Hierarchy**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

OK, why this won't work in your case. Your taxonomy name is all wrong. You should never use any special characters or capital letters in taxonomy or custom post type names. **Only** use lowercase letters and underscores (`_`) in taxonomy names. From the codex:

> Name should only contain lowercase letters and the underscore character, and not be more than 32 characters long (database structure restriction).

Lets break down what is happening. Your template name looks like this *taxonomy-ait-dir-item-category-events*. This is what Wordpress reads when it sees your template:

- Your taxonomy is called *ait* and
- your term is called *dir*,
- the rest after *dir* makes no sense at all.

Wordpress uses a hyphen (`-`) to separate names, so that is why it reads your template as above. So because the taxonomy *ait* doesn't exists, Wordpress will default to use the *taxonomy.php* template. Also, everything after *dir* makes no sense and doesn't fall into the hierarchy

**SOLUTION**

You should rename your taxonomy to at least something like *ait_dir_item_category* and then name your template *taxonomy-ait_dir_item_category-events.php*

Comment: Gave you an upvote for this solution @goose